# make boxes that are outside the viewport visible

Tags: css

[image]
SOme of the boxes in this webpage are hidden, they are outside the viewport. how can I 'push them down' to make them fully visible?

thanks!

Comment: How did you put them there in the first place?

Comment: I run a script that changed the page... they just got there :)